# Better way of saying "those who are curious"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I am writing a note in which I want to ask (curious) readers to refer another paper.
The phrase curious minded comes to mind, but it seems somewhat awkward.

Is there a better way to convey similar import?

Comment: For curious minds

Comment: The ordinary way would be with a footnote. If you can't do that, a parenthetical "(Curious readers may refer to `[insert reference]`)" is OK.

Comment: *"For further information see..."* Only the curious will bother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

> *[**For those of you who are interested**](http://books.google.fr/books?id=MGS7AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA220&dq=%22for+those+of+you+who+are+interested+in%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=tqhhU-ueJoXvOdyGgOgE&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22for%20those%20of%20you%20who%20are%20interested%20in%22&f=false) (in...), there is/you may*...
>
> *[**For those of you who are curious**](https://www.google.fr/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=pt-BR&q=%22for+those+of+you+who+are+curious+about%22&btnG=#hl=pt-BR&q=%22For+those+of+you+who+are+curious+about%22&start=10&tbm=bks) (about...),  there is/you may*...

Or, more formally:

> *Curious (or [**inquiring**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inquiring)) minds may refer to*...

Answer (score 4):

**Inquisitive** may be used also to describe it.

- Inclined to investigate; eager for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

**Meticulousness** or those interested in the [(noun) strict attention to minute details](http://mnemonicdictionary.com/?word=meticulosity%20)